# LASSO regression implementation without python libraries

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, lasso-regression, regularized

I am a python newbie and seriously searching for a python implementation of LASSO without the use of python libraries (e.g sklearn etc.)

I am particularly interested in this to help me understand how the underlying maths translates to python code. To this end, I will prefer the bare python implementation of LASSO without python libraries using any sample dataset.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Built-in data types are not very well suited to that task. So any implementation is likely going to use at least numpy because there is just no reason to avoid it.

Comment: @LukasNeugebaue, yes numpy, pandas etc. is okay. They are indeed necessary to deal with the data types etc. but not anything like sklearn that already has the lasso function written. What i really would like to see is how the maths for lasso is translated into a workable python code without use of already written libraries for lasso.

Comment: Then I don't get the question. LASSO is somehow written in python IN sklearn. You can look at the source code in sklearn to see how it's implemented. That will be a bit of work though because LASSO inherits from ElasticNet which inherits from LinearModel.

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer is would not recommend that, the implementation is in Cython, and difficult to understand for a newcomer (handles case where the gram matrix is precomputed, etc).

Answer (score 3):

First, your question is ill-posed because there exist many algorithms to solve the Lasso.
The most popular right now is coordinate descent. Here's the skeleton of the algo (without stopping criterion). I have used numba/jit because for loops can be slow in python.

```
import numpy as np

from numba import njit

@njit
def ST(x, u):
    "Soft thresholding of x at level u"""
    return np.sign(x) * np.maximum(np.abs(x) - u, 0.)



@njit
def cd_solver(X, y, alpha, max_iter):
    n_samples, n_features = X.shape


    beta = np.zeros(n_features)
    R = y.copy()  # residuals y - X @ beta
    lc = (X ** 2).sum(axis=0)  # lipschitz constants for coordinate descent
    for t in range(max_iter):
        for j in range(n_features):
            old = beta[j]
            beta[j] = ST(old + X[:, j].dot(R) / lc[j], alpha / lc[j])

            # keep residuals up to date
            if old != beta[j]:
                R += (old - beta[j]) * X[:, j]


        # I'll leave it up to you to implement a proper stopping criterion

    return beta



X = np.random.randn(100, 200)
y = np.random.randn(100)

if not np.isfortran(X):
    X = np.asfortranarray(X)        

alpha_max = np.max(np.abs(X.T.dot(y)))

cd_solver(X, y, alpha_max / 2., 100)
```

You can also try with proximal gradient/ISTA, but from my experience it's way slower than CD.